# Getting Voice Over's Speech rate from my app

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

I'm building an app for iOS, in Swift.

Is there a way I can get the speech rate used in the iPhone's accessibility settings ?

Thanks,
Shahar

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Nope. I wanted to know the speech rate to simulate same speed when using 3rd party text-to-speech engines. At the end I've decided to use VoiceOver as a text-to-speech.